# "zsh: illegal hardware instruction hhvm" when running Hackland on VSCode, Macbook Pro M1

Tags: visual-studio-code, apple-m1, hhvm, hacklang

I'm trying to run a Hacklang code and also a Hacklang website on VSCode, Mac Pro M1. However, I keep getting the errors

> zsh: illegal hardware instruction  hhvm hello.hack

and

> zsh: illegal hardware instruction  hhvm -m server -p 8080

I follow the instructions from the [Hack docs](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/getting-started/getting-started), but it seems not to be working.

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

HHVM does not support ARM64 Macs (M1+): https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/8875

I suggest switching to PHP.